# JAVASCRIPT : Check whether there is enough space for an element(say tooltip) to be visible completely in the visible window area

Tags: javascript, coordinates

When the page is not scrolled, window and document coordinates are the same and share the zero point...

I want the coordinates of an element(say tooltip), according to the visible area(after scrolling and resizing the window).

Basically, I want to find whether there is enough space foe an element (say tooltip), in the visible area after scrolling or resizing.

Can anybody give me the solution in javascript (not jquery)

Hope, the question properly explained.

Comment: So get the location of the element. Add the width and height and see if it overflows the browser dimensions. What do you have problem with getting?

Comment: I have a tooltip on a page, and I want that after scrooling or resizing the page...the tooltip should adjust itself so that it can appear completely (not some part of it), in the visible area.

Comment: Basically, I want to calculate the available space(after scrooling and resize) and make tooltip to adjust accordingly so that it can be visible completely in the visible area

Comment: So you listen for the resize event of the page and adjust the dimensions.